# Axis2 : Web client for Axis2

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

I have developed  a Webservice using Axis2 , made a .aar file from it and deployed it inside the Axis2.war services directory .
All this works fine .

I also need  to write a Web client for it , so now my question is  do i need to make another .war to deploy the client , or can i keep my files inside Axis2.war ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it depends on the place you need to access the web service. If you want to access web service in your standalone application you can put the client code there. If you want to access it in another web app you need to put the client code inside that application .war file.

Comment: hey thanks a lot Amila Suriarachchi , i saw your website and found that you are working for Apache Axis2 , great that you are taking time for answering forum questions as well .